# How to activate a responsive top navigation button for mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently learning Bootstrap and basic HTML at the moment, and I would like to have a navigation button (hamburger) to simplify my navbar for mobile. It's all there, when I resize my window on my desktop, but it does not work when I look on my nexus. Do I have to add a media query? I have just heard of them. Here is what I have in **HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="delightful-header"><p>Delighful Days Daycare</p></div>
                    <div class="tagline"><p>"Where Everyday Is Delightful"</p></div>
                </div>
                <nav class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="index.html" id="homenav">HOME</a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="about-us.html" id="aboutnav">ABOUT US</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pricing.html" id="pricing">PRICING</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact-us.html" id="contactnav">CONTACT US</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: compare your html with http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Im afraid I'm not following you

Comment: Actually your html structure is not as bootstrap documentation have

Comment: Would that effect the navbar on mobiles?

Comment: **Bootstrap** has a set rule to when to hide its element and when to not. In your case the navigation bar will hide after a certain width and at that same width the button appear to start the toggle process. So if you want to do this action before Bootstrap does, you have to define that from that width using `media-query`.

Comment: Despite all the comments above your code seems to work just fine with Bootstrap 3.3.7: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/8720wy74/